# AWS Elastic Beanstalk SignalR Handshake was canceled error

Tags: websocket, signalr, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, iis-10

I have a real-time application that is using SignalR. On development environment it's working perfectly so as in Azure. I redeployed the same app on AWS Elastic Beanstalk using IIS 10 on Windows server 2019 platform, I got the `Handshake was canceled` error. When I got this error on my development environment and Azure, all I did to fix this issue was to turn on Web Sockets. But I realize in  AWS EB I do not have this possibility.

I'm wondering if the IIS 10 AWS EB support this feature. If it doesn't, is there any alternative to the SignalR?